# How to rework a QTreeView with column headers into a QTableView?

Tags: python, pyqt, pyside, qtableview, qtreeview

I have a QTreeView with column header filters but would like to use a QTableView.

Problem: I don't know how to rework the header functionality for a QTableView.
If I just switch the utilized class from QTreeView() to QTableView() I get dozens of error
like `AttributeError: 'QTableView' object has no attribute 'setHeader'`

Currently it looks like this (see MRE below):
[image]

I would like to build a TableView with column header filter like this:
(Courtesy of "[DB Browser for SQLite](https://sqlitebrowser.org/)")
[image]

After the rework of the 1st reply I have the following when I remove
`self.treeView.verticalHeader().hide()`:
[image]

MRE:

```
import sys
import re
from PyQt5 import QtWidgets, QtGui, QtCore, QtSql

COUNT_PERS_COLS = 3
col_persID, col_persLAST_NAME, col_persFIRST_NAME = range(COUNT_PERS_COLS)

db = QtSql.QSqlDatabase.addDatabase("QSQLITE")
db.setDatabaseName(':memory:')

modelQuery = QtSql.QSqlQueryModel()
modelTable = QtSql.QSqlRelationalTableModel()

def _human_key(key):
    parts = re.split(r'(\d*\.\d+|\d+)', key)
    return tuple((e.swapcase() if i % 2 == 0 else float(e))
            for i, e in enumerate(parts))

class FilterHeader(QtWidgets.QHeaderView):
    filterActivated = QtCore.pyqtSignal()

    def __init__(self, parent):
        super().__init__(QtCore.Qt.Horizontal, parent)
        self._editors = []
        self._padding = 4
        self.setStretchLastSection(True)        
        self.setSectionResizeMode(QtWidgets.QHeaderView.Stretch)
        self.setDefaultAlignment(QtCore.Qt.AlignLeft | QtCore.Qt.AlignVCenter)
        self.setSortIndicatorShown(False)
        self.setSectionsMovable(True)
        self.sectionResized.connect(self.adjustPositions)
        parent.horizontalScrollBar().valueChanged.connect(self.adjustPositions)

    def setFilterBoxes(self, count):
        while self._editors:
            editor = self._editors.pop()
            editor.deleteLater()
        for index in range(count):
            editor = QtWidgets.QLineEdit(self.parent())            
            editor.setPlaceholderText('Filter')
            editor.setClearButtonEnabled(True)
            editor.returnPressed.connect(self.filterActivated.emit)
            self._editors.append(editor)
        self.adjustPositions()

    def sizeHint(self):
        size = super().sizeHint()
        if self._editors:
            height = self._editors[0].sizeHint().height()
            size.setHeight(size.height() + height + self._padding)
        return size

    def updateGeometries(self):
        if self._editors:
            height = self._editors[0].sizeHint().height()
            self.setViewportMargins(0, 0, 0, height + self._padding)
        else:
            self.setViewportMargins(0, 0, 0, 0)
        super().updateGeometries()
        self.adjustPositions()

    def adjustPositions(self):
        for index, editor in enumerate(self._editors):
            height = editor.sizeHint().height()
            editor.move(
                self.sectionPosition(index) - self.offset() + 2,
                height + (self._padding // 2))
            editor.resize(self.sectionSize(index), height)

    def filterText(self, index):
        if 0 <= index < len(self._editors):
            return self._editors[index].text()
        return ''

    def setFilterText(self, index, text):
        if 0 <= index < len(self._editors):
            self._editors[index].setText(text)

    def clearFilters(self):
        for editor in self._editors:
            editor.clear()        


class HumanProxyModel(QtCore.QSortFilterProxyModel):
    def lessThan(self, source_left, source_right):
        data_left = source_left.data()
        data_right = source_right.data()
        if type(data_left) == type(data_right) == str:
            return _human_key(data_left) < _human_key(data_right)
        return super(HumanProxyModel, self).lessThan(source_left, source_right)

    @property
    def filters(self):
        if not hasattr(self, "_filters"):
            self._filters = []
        return self._filters

    @filters.setter
    def filters(self, filters):
        print(f"filters() called.")        

        self._filters = filters
        self.invalidateFilter()                

    def filterAcceptsRow(self, sourceRow, sourceParent):        
        for i, text in self.filters:
            if 0 <= i < self.columnCount():
                ix = self.sourceModel().index(sourceRow, i, sourceParent)                
                data = ix.data()
                if text not in data:
                    return False            
        return True        

class winMain(QtWidgets.QMainWindow):
    def __init__(self, parent=None):        
        super().__init__(parent)                
        self.setupUi()
        self.setGeometry(300,200,700,500)        

        self.show()        

    def createPersonModel(self,parent):        
        model = QtGui.QStandardItemModel(0, COUNT_PERS_COLS, parent)                
        model.setHorizontalHeaderLabels(['ID', 'Last Name', 'First Name'])

        return model

    def addPerson(self, model, id, last_name, first_name):        
        model.insertRow(0)        
        model.setData(model.index(0, col_persID), id)
        model.setData(model.index(0, col_persLAST_NAME), last_name)
        model.setData(model.index(0, col_persFIRST_NAME), first_name)

    def handleFilterActivated(self):                
        header = self.treeView.header()
        filters = []

        for i in range(header.count()):
            text = header.filterText(i)
            if text:        
                filters.append((i, text))

        proxy = self.treeView.model()
        proxy.filters = filters        

    def setupUi(self):
        self.centralwidget = QtWidgets.QWidget(self)        
        self.horizontalLayout = QtWidgets.QHBoxLayout(self.centralwidget)        

        self.treeView = QtWidgets.QTreeView(self.centralwidget)        

        self.treeView.setSortingEnabled(True)
        self.treeView.setAlternatingRowColors(True)        
        self.treeView.setEditTriggers(QtWidgets.QAbstractItemView.NoEditTriggers)
        self.treeView.setSelectionMode(QtWidgets.QAbstractItemView.ExtendedSelection)
        self.treeView.setAnimated(True)
        self.treeView.setItemsExpandable(True)

        self.horizontalLayout.addWidget(self.treeView)
        self.setCentralWidget(self.centralwidget)

        header = FilterHeader(self.treeView)        
        self.treeView.setHeader(header)        

        self.statusBar = QtWidgets.QStatusBar()
        self.setStatusBar(self.statusBar)        

        modelTable.setTable("person")
        self.treeView.setModel(modelTable)

        proxy = HumanProxyModel(self)
        proxy.setSourceModel(modelTable)
        self.treeView.setModel(proxy)        

        header.setFilterBoxes(modelTable.columnCount())
        header.filterActivated.connect(self.handleFilterActivated)        


def create_sample_data():     
    modelQuery.setQuery("""CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS country (                                    
                                    id   INTEGER PRIMARY KEY UNIQUE NOT NULL,
                                    name TEXT
                                    )""")

    modelQuery.setQuery("""CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS person (
                                   id         INTEGER PRIMARY KEY UNIQUE NOT NULL,
                                   persId     TEXT,
                                   lastName   TEXT,
                                   firstName  TEXT,
                                   country_id INTEGER NOT NULL DEFAULT 3,
              FOREIGN KEY (country_id) REFERENCES country(id)
                                   )""")

    modelQuery.setQuery("INSERT INTO country (id, name) VALUES (0, 'None')")    
    modelQuery.setQuery("INSERT INTO country (id, name) VALUES (1, 'Angola')")    
    modelQuery.setQuery("INSERT INTO country (id, name) VALUES (2, 'Serbia')")
    modelQuery.setQuery("INSERT INTO country (id, name) VALUES (3, 'Georgia')")

    modelQuery.setQuery("INSERT INTO person (id, persId, lastName, firstName, country_id) VALUES (1, '1001', 'Martin', 'Robert', 1)")
    modelQuery.setQuery("INSERT INTO person (id, persId, lastName, firstName, country_id) VALUES (2, '1002', 'Smith', 'Brad', 2)")
    modelQuery.setQuery("INSERT INTO person (id, persId, lastName, firstName, country_id) VALUES (3, '1003', 'Smith', 'Angelina', 3)")

if __name__ == '__main__':                         
    app = QtWidgets.QApplication(sys.argv)         

    create_sample_data()        

    window = winMain()    
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

Added 2nd screenshot from "DB Browser for SQLite":
[image]

Comment: QTreeView has only one (horizontal) header, QTableView [has two](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qtableview.html#visual-appearance): "The table has a vertical header that can be obtained using the [`verticalHeader()`](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qtableview.html#verticalHeader) function, and a horizontal header that is available through the [`horizontalHeader()`](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qtableview.html#horizontalHeader) function."

Answer (score 1):

QTreeView only has one header (the horizontal one), on the other hand QTableView has 2. Also, QTableView does not have branches so it does not have the `setAnimated()` and `setItemsExpandable()` methods either.

```py
def handleFilterActivated(self):
    # header = self.treeView.header()
    header = self.treeView.horizontalHeader()
    filters = []

    for i in range(header.count()):
        text = header.filterText(i)
        if text:
            filters.append((i, text))

    proxy = self.treeView.model()
    proxy.filters = filters

def setupUi(self):
    self.centralwidget = QtWidgets.QWidget(self)
    self.horizontalLayout = QtWidgets.QHBoxLayout(self.centralwidget)

    self.treeView = QtWidgets.QTableView(self.centralwidget)

    self.treeView.setSortingEnabled(True)
    self.treeView.setAlternatingRowColors(True)
    self.treeView.setEditTriggers(QtWidgets.QAbstractItemView.NoEditTriggers)
    self.treeView.setSelectionMode(QtWidgets.QAbstractItemView.ExtendedSelection)
    # self.treeView.setAnimated(True)
    # self.treeView.setItemsExpandable(True)

    self.horizontalLayout.addWidget(self.treeView)
    self.setCentralWidget(self.centralwidget)

    header = FilterHeader(self.treeView)
    # self.treeView.setHeader(header)
    self.treeView.setHorizontalHeader(header)
    self.treeView.verticalHeader().hide()

    self.statusBar = QtWidgets.QStatusBar()
    self.setStatusBar(self.statusBar)

    modelTable.setTable("person")
    modelTable.select()
    self.treeView.setModel(modelTable)

    proxy = HumanProxyModel(self)
    proxy.setSourceModel(modelTable)
    self.treeView.setModel(proxy)

    header.setFilterBoxes(modelTable.columnCount())
    header.filterActivated.connect(self.handleFilterActivated)
```

Comment: Thanks, this works out! You have also hidden the verticalHeader(). I would like to see the verticalHeader(). Only problem is then, that the QLineEdit do not align left with the columns. I assume that's why you have hidden the verticalHeader(). Is there any chance to move the QLineEdits to align correct with the columns when the verticalHeader() remains visible?

Comment: I would like to achieve this, as in "DB Browser for SQLite" program (written in C++):

see updated original post for 2nd screenshot